# How to drag a formula down (autofill) using VBA after finding the first blank cell

Tags: excel, vba, autofill

I need some help dragging a string ("Decliners") down a column in excel. I know how to do this if I knew what cell was my starting point, but I first have to find the first blank row in my data set.
 Once I've found my first blank row, I need to drag my string down from there in column C3.
 This string is being dragged down just one column. I also don't know the range of this data set, given that it is dynamic.

Essentially I just need to recreate the action of double clicking the bottom right of the cell and the word "Decliners" fill to the bottom of the data set.

Code to select the first blank cell in worksheet:

```
Dim Pastesheet As Worksheet
Dim Decliners As String
Decliners = "Decliners"

Set Pastesheet = Worksheets("Ent Gainers_Decliners")
Pastesheet.Range("C3").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
'Where I need the word "Decliners" dragged down from the cell selected
```

[image: Spreadsheet picture]

Comment: You may need to specify which column determines the length of the values for column C and whether column C already has some values that should not be disturbed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
With Pastesheet
    .Range(.Range("C3").End(xlDown).Offset(1),.Cells(.Rows.Count,4).End(xlUp).Offset(,-1)).Value = Decliners
End With
```

This piece of code will set the value of the variable `Decliners` from the row after the last data set from Range `C3` down until the last corresponding row of used data in column `D` for column `C`.

Comment: Good catch on locating the last row in column B; I missed that myself.

Comment: @Jeeped - I was about to write something to you, but you deleted it :)

Comment: So I tried this and nothing happened. I replaced `end(xlUp)` with `end(xlDown)` and the entire column filled with "Decliners". Not really sure why it's not working.

Comment: I think you might have to filter the selection with SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).

Comment: @Davey - can you edit your question with a sample data structure or screenshot. Perhaps what I imagined your data set to look like is not what it looks like.

Comment: Let me know if you are able to view that picture. The site is blocked on my computer. I need to drag "Decliners" in the blank cell ("C552") right after "gainers"...note it won't always start at that cell.

Comment: @Davey - much easier to help now :) See the edited answer.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks Scott! Really appreciate it